# AudioToggle is not defined

Tags: cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins

I have installed the `audiotoggle-cordova-plugin` from `github`.

The sample code provided for this plugin didn't working in `phonegap` app.

Here is the sample code:

```
AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.EARPIECE).
```

In console i always get the error:

> AudioToggle is not defined

Comment: Are you checking for a DeviceReady event before calling the audiotoggle fn?

Comment: Yups. I have added the DeviceReady event.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable before @Component

```
declare var AudioToggle:any;
```

make sure you have already added audiotoggle plugin by

```
$ cordova plugin ls
```

if not then

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-audiotoggle --save
```